# Get query results for all date values besides current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get values for data excluding current month and taking this year into account.

What I currently have is the following

```
WHERE 1=1
    AND CAST(created_at AS DATE) >= '2018-01-01'
    AND MONTH(CAST(created_at AS DATE)) != MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Obviously this will also exclude 2018 current month data as well which I want to prevent.

I've checked different solutions online but failed to apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
where created_at < dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate as date))
```

This is also sargable -- a mouthful that means that an index can be used for the query.

You can also write this as:

```
where created_at < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

This is actually better and clearer.

Comment: wow never saw the "datefromparts" used this way- very ingenious and appealing. perfect solution thank you

Answer (score 1):

The correct WHERE clause related on your question will be

```
   WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND (DATEADD(dd, -1 ,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)))
```